# Create server proxy

Tags: proxy

I'm searching for a way to proxy traffic to one ip to another. For example: I want to proxy everything to 1.1.1.1:1111 to 2.2.2.2:2222. I also only want to proxy the port itself. It is also important that it isn't just a dns record, because the client should not notice that 1.1.1.1 is 2.2.2.2.

I never worked with proxy until now and I haven't found anything about it, because everytime I search about proxying I just find how to create proxys which hide the client, not the server. As services like cloudflare using it I'm sure it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of proxy are you referring to?

1) In case you want to serve web pages etc (or even some other purposes), have a look at Squid (http://www.squid-cache.org/)

2) In case you want to divert all traffic from one port on one server to a different port on another server, you need something like jTCPfwd (http://jtcpfwd.sourceforge.net/)

In case 2, you can also have a look at stunnel, which will also SSL wrap your data  (https://www.stunnel.org)